# Incrementing values, alternate way of doing this that won't use MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, memcache, alternative-php-cache

I need to count impressions of a .php script that is accessed via web. Right now I do this in a 1 line MySQL table and just increment the value. This works fine usually but when the server has traffic bursts (hundreds of requests/second) everything gets delayed and the increment SQL statements start to pop up in MySQL's slow queries log.
I tried to count via APC but it "loses" values, that is, when I run a simple ab test command like

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://example.com/script.php
```

only ~50 new impressions are counted while on MySQL 100 are counted.
I also tried to count impressions via **memcache**, it works better (that is, its able to keep up with more simultaneous connections) but it also fails to count everything after 50 or 100 simultaneous connections.

I was wondering if there is anybody aware of a good solution to this problem?

Comment: what is wrong with parsing log data after the fact?

Comment: What does your SQL look like that increments the value?

Comment: @n8whnp: well, I need the data in real time and also I don't have the logs activated.

Comment: @EricPetroelje I am not sure I understand your question?

Comment: @Alex - you must have an SQL statement that increments the value in the table.  What does that look like?

Comment: @EricPetroelje it looks like this: UPDATE DailyStatsInMemory SET pdfs=pdfs+1, pdfs_total=pdfs_total+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I chose to use a MEMORY table instead the usual INNODB one. While the solution isn't perfect it works much better than just using INNODB for this. I also applied this solution on a number of other tables where data integrity wasn't crucial and the results were positive.